# Is there a API to query billing recurring-items?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I need the date of the day before a number is billed automatically by twilio. The day itself is descripted [here](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223135227-How-and-when-are-phone-numbers-billed-). I can see this information [here](https://www.twilio.com/console/billing/recurring-items) in a browser. Is there beside "web scraping" this page a way to get this informations from twilio (for a number)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can look up the date your Phone Number was created, using the [Incoming Phone Numbers resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers) (you can either [list all your numbers](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers?code-sample=code-list-all-incomingphonenumber-of-your-account&code-language=curl&code-sdk-version=json) or [fetch each number individually](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers?code-sample=code-get-an-incomingphonenumber&code-language=curl&code-sdk-version=json)). Each Incoming Phone Number has a date on which it was created (the `DateCreated` attribute) which you could then use to calculate, based on the information you already know, when it will be billed.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in this case I have to calculate the day when it will be billed myself, including the change of the billing day and leap years and so on. This is possible, but I wanted to avoid to implemented it, because the informations are already available on Twilio. But not with an API call, if I understand your answer correct. I guess special credentials are needed for that.

Comment: There isn't an API for what you're asking for I'm afraid. What I suggested is the best way I can think of to create that yourself.